# How to add an image with Resize Adorner to RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a command that adds an image to the FlowDocument of RichTextBox, but when I wrapped it in ResizeAdorner, the image disappeared? How do I add an image with ResizeAdorner to a RichTextBox of FlowDocument?

command

```
 public ICommand ImageCommand { get; set; }
    private bool CanImageExecute(object parameter) => true;
    private void OnImageExecute(object parameter)
    {
        var file = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        file.ShowDialog();
        if(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower() is ".png" || System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower() is ".jpg")
        {
            var BitMapImage = new BitmapImage();
            BitMapImage.BeginInit();
            BitMapImage.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(file.FileName));
            BitMapImage.EndInit();

            if (_TextSelected is null) return;
            if (TextSelected.End.Paragraph is null) FileSystem.FileCurent.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph());

            FileSystem.FileCurent.Blocks.InsertBefore(TextSelected.End.Paragraph, new BlockUIContainer(new Image { Source = BitMapImage}));
        }
    }
```

command with wrapped image

```
 public ICommand ImageCommand { get; set; }
    private bool CanImageExecute(object parameter) => true;
    private void OnImageExecute(object parameter)
    {
        var file = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        file.ShowDialog();
        if(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower() is ".png" || System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower() is ".jpg")
        {
            var BitMapImage = new BitmapImage();
            BitMapImage.BeginInit();
            BitMapImage.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(file.FileName));
            BitMapImage.EndInit();

            if (_TextSelected is null) return;
            if (TextSelected.End.Paragraph is null) FileSystem.FileCurent.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph());

            FileSystem.FileCurent.Blocks.InsertBefore(TextSelected.End.Paragraph, new BlockUIContainer(new ResizeAdorner(new Image { Source = BitMapImage })));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. The thing was that `AdornerLayer` can be obtained only after loading the component.

Here is the working command

```
 public ICommand ImageCommand { get; set; }
    private bool CanImageExecute(object parameter) => true;
    private void OnImageExecute(object parameter)
    {
        var file = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        file.ShowDialog();
        if(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower() is ".png" || System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower() is ".jpg")
        {
            var BitMapImage = new BitmapImage();
            BitMapImage.BeginInit();
            BitMapImage.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(file.FileName));
            BitMapImage.EndInit();

            if (_TextSelected is null) return;
            if (TextSelected.End.Paragraph is null) FileSystem.FileCurent.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph());
            var cont = new Border { Width = 100, Height = 100, Child = new Image { Source = BitMapImage } };
            FileSystem.FileCurent.Blocks.InsertBefore(TextSelected.End.Paragraph, new Paragraph( new InlineUIContainer(cont)));
            cont.Loaded += (s, e) => { AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer((Grid)parameter).Add(new ResizeAdorner(cont)); };
        }
    }
```